# DataSift python API: Difference between datasift.client.subscribe and datasift.push.create_from_hash?

Tags: python, datasift-python

In reading over the API documentation it's not clear to me when I should be using [client.subscribe](http://datasift.github.io/datasift-python/datasift.html#datasift.client.Client.subscribe) versus [datasift.push.create_from_hash](http://datasift.github.io/datasift-python/datasift.html#datasift.push.Push.create_from_hash).

In digging into the source code, they appear to be doing different things under the hood.

Are they interchangeable?

Comment: Don't datasift have a customer support contact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered on the Datasift community forum [here](http://community.datasift.com/t/what-is-the-difference-between-datasift-client-subscribe-and-datasift-push-create-from-hash-in-the-python-api/1003).

> The client.subscribe method will start a connection using our streaming service, whereas datasift.push.create_from_hash will create a delivery job using our robust push delivery service. Push will send the data directly to a specified destination.

Answer (score 1):

client.subscribe is used to subscribe to a stream [using websockets](http://dev.datasift.com/docs/streaming-api/websockets), while push.create_from_hash is used to create a Push connector to send you the data using [other connectors](http://dev.datasift.com/docs/push/connectors)

Comment: So what is the answer to "are they interchangeable"?  Any additional information on the differences between the two would also help.

Comment: They provide two different delivery mechanisms as Andi mentioned. Take a look at the section in DataSift's documentation on [What's the difference between Push and Streaming?](http://dev.datasift.com/docs/push). Push (so the ```datasift.push.create_from_hash``` method) tends to be the recommended delivery mechanism as DataSift can guarantee delivery here.